# Калькулятор с select

Tags: html, jquery, select

Вопрос: как вычислять по выбранному селекту?

```js
$('#obs, #visotp, #etagey, .factors, #mainresult').bind('input', calcAndShow);

function calcAndShow() {
  var v1 = parseFloat($("#obs").val());
  var v2 = parseFloat($("#visotp").val());
  var v3 = parseFloat($("#etagey").val());
  var v4 = parseFloat($('input[name="stena[]"]:checked').val());
  var v5 = $('#mainresult');
  var text, text2, summa, text3;
  text = 'Цена от:';
  text2 = v1 * v2 * v3 * v4;
  text3 = 'руб.'
  if (text2 === text2) {

  } else {

    return 0;
  }

  var res = (text2 + '').replace(/(\d)(?=(\d\d\d)+([^\d]|$))/g, '$1 ');
  summa = text + ' ' + res + ' ' + text3;
  $('#mainresults').val(summa);


}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="" method="post" class=" ajax_form" id="maincals" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <div class="row">

    <div class="col-12 col-md-5 lfts">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-12 col-md-6 frmss">
          <label for="obs">Общая площадь дома</label>
          <input type="text" name="obs" id="obs" value="" data="Цена От">
          <span class="sup">м<sup>2</sup></span>
        </div>
        <div class="col-12 col-md-6 frmss">
          <div class="selects">
            <select name="visota" id="visotp">
              <option disabled="" selected="">Высота потолков</option>
              <option value="1">2,4 метра</option>
              <option value="1,06">2,7 метра</option>
              <option value="1,12">3 метра</option>
              <option value="1,18">3,3 метра</option>
            </select>
          </div>
          <div class="selects frmss">
            <select name="etagey" id="etagey">
              <option disabled="" selected="">Кол-во этажей</option>
              <option value="1,15">Один</option>
              <option value="1">Два</option>
              <option value="1">Три</option>
            </select>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-12 col-md-7 rightcalc">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-12 col-md-7">
          <span class="title"><span>Стены</span></span>
          <div class="row">
            <input type="hidden" name="stena[]" value="">
            <div class="col-12 col-md-6 rad">
              <div class="radiob">

                <input type="radio" class="factors" name="stena[]" value="15000" id="stena1">
                <label for="stena1" class="radios">Кирпич</label>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-12 col-md-6 rad">
              <div class="radiob">

                <input type="radio" class="factors" name="stena[]" value="14000" id="stena2">
                <label for="stena2" class="radios">Газоблок</label>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-12 col-md-6 rad">
              <div class="radiob">

                <input type="radio" class="factors" name="stena[]" value="12000" id="stena3">
                <label for="stena3" class="radios">Деревянный каркас</label>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-12 col-md-6 rad">
              <div class="radiob">

                <input type="radio" class="factors" name="stena[]" value="13000" id="stena4">
                <label for="stena4" class="radios">Блоки эконом</label>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-12 col-md-5 result">
          <span class="title">Стоимость Вашего дома:</span>

          <input type="text" name="result" id="mainresults" value="">
          <a href="#" class="resbtn" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#form2">Получить подробный расчет</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
```

Comment: `$("#visotp, #etagey").change(calcAndShow);`  ваш `bind`, кстати, устарел лет 5 назад.

Comment: чтобы пробелы в число вставить, лучше `toLocaleString()` использовать,  а не городить регулярки.

Comment: А можно чуть конкретней? $("#visotp, #etagey").change(calcAndShow);   - не совсем понимаю, что это и как с этим бороться

Comment: Если вы хотели, чтобы при смене выпадающего селекта вызывалась функция пересчета, то эта строка именно это и делает.

Answer (score 2):

Как бы и так почти всё работало... Подправил немного.

```js
$('#maincals').on('change input', calcAndShow);
function calcAndShow() {
  var v1 = parseFloat($("#obs").val());
  var v2 = parseFloat($("#visotp").val());
  var v3 = parseFloat($("#etagey").val());
  var v4 = parseFloat($('input[name="stena[]"]:checked').val());
  var v5 = $('#mainresult');
  var text, text2, summa, text3;
  text = 'Цена от:';
  text2 = v1 * v2 * v3 * v4 + 0.00001;
  text3 = 'руб.'
  if (text2 === text2) {} else {
    return 0;
  }
  var res = (text2.toFixed(2)).replace(/(\d)(?=(\d\d\d)+([^\d]|$))/g, '$1 ');
  summa = text + ' ' + res + ' ' + text3;
  $('#mainresults').val(summa);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="" method="post" class=" ajax_form" id="maincals" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-12 col-md-5 lfts">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-12 col-md-6 frmss">
          <label for="obs">Общая площадь дома</label>
          <input type="text" name="obs" id="obs" value="" data="Цена От">
          <span class="sup">м<sup>2</sup></span>
        </div>
        <div class="col-12 col-md-6 frmss">
          <div class="selects">
            <select name="visota" id="visotp">
              <option disabled selected>Высота потолков</option>
              <option value="1">2,4 метра</option>
              <option value="1.06">2,7 метра</option>
              <option value="1.12">3 метра</option>
              <option value="1.18">3,3 метра</option>
            </select>
          </div>
          <div class="selects frmss">
            <select name="etagey" id="etagey">
              <option disabled selected>Кол-во этажей</option>
              <option value="1.15">Один</option>
              <option value="1">Два</option>
              <option value="1">Три</option>
            </select>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-12 col-md-7 rightcalc">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-12 col-md-7">
          <span class="title"><span>Стены</span></span>
          <div class="row">
            <input type="hidden" name="stena[]" value="">
            <div class="col-12 col-md-6 rad">
              <div class="radiob">
                <input type="radio" class="factors" name="stena[]" value="15000" id="stena1" checked>
                <label for="stena1" class="radios">Кирпич</label>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-12 col-md-6 rad">
              <div class="radiob">
                <input type="radio" class="factors" name="stena[]" value="14000" id="stena2">
                <label for="stena2" class="radios">Газоблок</label>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-12 col-md-6 rad">
              <div class="radiob">

                <input type="radio" class="factors" name="stena[]" value="12000" id="stena3">
                <label for="stena3" class="radios">Деревянный каркас</label>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-12 col-md-6 rad">
              <div class="radiob">
                <input type="radio" class="factors" name="stena[]" value="13000" id="stena4">
                <label for="stena4" class="radios">Блоки эконом</label>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-12 col-md-5 result">
          <span class="title">Стоимость Вашего дома:</span>
          <input type="text" name="result" id="mainresults" value="">
          <a href="#" class="resbtn" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#form2">Получить подробный расчет</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```